# \longtable with imported csv data

Tags: tables, longtable, csv

I am trying to spread an imported csv table on two pages. Somehow this doesn't work. Does anyone have advice for me?

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}
    \csvautotabular[]{Tables/semi-endogenous.csv}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
\end{landscape}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The landscape environment should be used inside of document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.